# Django possible to nest prefetch related?

Tags: django, prefetch

Suppose I have the following models.

```
class Item(models.Model):

    seller = models.ForeignKey('seller.Seller')


class ItemSet(models.Model):

    items = models.ManyToManyField("Item", related_name="special_items")
```

What I'd like to do is

For a given seller, retrieve all items which is stored as special_items in ItemSet.

The following code is what I come up with, havent tried, just a hunch it won't work. :(
(I want to retrieve item_founds and item_specials)

```
item_founds = Item.objects.filter(seller=seller).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "special_items",
        queryset=Items.objects.prefetch_related("items")
    )
)

item_specials = Item.objects.none()
for item_found in item_founds.all():
    for special_item in item_found.special_items.all():
        item_specials |= special_item.items.all()
```

Comment: Well your usage of `prefetch_related` doesn't seem to be so far off, so maybe test it and provide more information what doesnt work for you!

Answer (score 0):

In Django you must always perform your queries from the model that you want in the end. In your case that's `seller.Seller`. Otherwise you get both poor code and risk bad performance (like in your code where you have two lookups inside a loop...)

```
Seller.objects.get(pk=<seller id here>).prefetch_related(
    'items',
    queryset=Item.objects.exclude(
        special_items=None
    ),
    to_attr='item_specials'
)
```

Which should give you a `Seller` with a set of special items in `item_specials` attribute.